# "lightnovelapi" PIP,Conda & Python 3 Module Installation Error

Tags: python, api, rest, pip, conda

I'm having troubles running the [lightnovelapi](https://github.com/raember/lightnovelapi), a Python library for accessing text from lightnovel websites, on any `{file_name}.py`
executable file.

I have tried:

1. Running `pip3 install lightnovelapi`.
2. Running `python -m pip install lightnovel`.
3. Running `which python` and `which pip` and using all versions of python and pip listed in the combinations of `Steps 1 & 2` above.
4. Switching from originally using **Windows 10** to **MAC OS**.
5. Downloading `condas` and creating `conda envs` and running steps 1-3.

Any advice on how to successfully install,import and run this library?

Comment: `pip install lightnovelapi` works for me. What errors are you getting?

Comment: No module named 'lightnovelapi'

Comment: **To add to Above**:
So Far I've Used:
6. manually installed library into site-packages conda\envs

Comment: So Far I've been Using: ```lightnovel-crawler``` instead and that library works fine

Comment: What is the ouput you get from the installations? Do you get some kind of error? Please add that and also some detail of how you run your python script by editing your question